# Get nested object - but identifier is part of needed object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

How do I get a nested object from a selected document?

If this is my document, which I get with `Collection.findOne({ _id: 'dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF'})`...

```
{
    "_id" : "dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF",
    "points" : [
        {
            "id" : "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK",
            "coordinates" : [
                433,
                215
            ],
            "content" : "anything"
        },
        {
            "id" : "iwSM98W5PD87BtcLa",
            "coordinates" : [
                666,
                186
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

... I need to get the complete data of the point with the id Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK. So my result should look like:

```
result = {
    "id" : "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK",
    "coordinates" : [
        433,
        215
    ],
    "content" : "anything"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply filter the `points` array, with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), like this

```
console.log(data.points.filter(function(obj) {
  return obj.id === "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK";
})[0]);
// { id: 'Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK' coordinates: [ 433, 215 ],  content: 'anything' }
```

We just take the first element from the filtered result array. If you want to get all the elements, which have the specific id, then just remove the subscript.

---

If your environment supports [ECMAScript 2015's Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), then you can write the same as

```
console.log(data.points.filter((obj) => obj.id === "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK")[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
    "_id": "dZXr2Pg7Ak4M5aYWF",
        "points": [{
        "id": "Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK",
            "coordinates": [433, 215],
            "content": "anything"
    }, {
        "id": "iwSM98W5PD87BtcLa",
            "coordinates": [666, 186]
    }]
};
function finder(id){
    for(i=0;i<data.points.length;i++){
        if(data.points[i].id==id){
            return data.points[i];
        }
    }
}
var result = finder("Gwf5BzorXyYBZSEzK");
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```